# Generate 29 days of February in .NET

Tags: vb.net, datetime, leap-year

I am trying to populate a `dropdown` with `No.of days` generated by the `system` by the following code

```
Sub LoadDay()
        Try
            ddlDay.Items.Clear()
            For i As Integer = 1 To System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Today.Year, ddlMonth.SelectedValue)
                ddlDay.Items.Add(New ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString("00")))
            Next
            ddlDay.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--Select--", -999))
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Problem is, for the month of February it shows only 28 days because the following code generates `Days` on the basis of current year and this year isn't a leap year

```
System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Today.Year, ddlMonth.SelectedValue)
```

How can I fix it to always show 29 days for the month of Februaray?

Comment: `System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(2000, ddlMonth.SelectedValue)`?

Comment: @erikkallen: Nice, the simple hacks are the best.

Comment: You should remove that empty catch block from your code. It's considered bad pratice to swallow exceptions like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DayInMonth in DateTime

```
Dim dayinMonth As String
dayinMonth = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(2012, 2)
```

This allow you to know the day in month for 2015 February. Parameter inside stand for year and month

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested in knowing what your requirment is that you have to be able to select invalid days, but, if you don't want your days to change based on the year, just create your own array of days. This leaves your intent a bit more clear than putting an arbitrary year in the DaysInMonth function.

```
            Dim Days = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}
            ddlDay.Items.Clear()
            For i As Integer = 1 To Days(ddlMonth.SelectedValue-1)
                ddlDay.Items.Add(New ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString("00")))
            Next
            ddlDay.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--Select--", -999))
```